# Can't figure out what's wrong with this

Tags: php, rounding

I tried calling up: `echo PrettyTime( time() - 70 * 60 )`, expecting it would say `1 hour ago`, but it instead says `70 minutes ago`, and I can't seem to figure out why... I think it may be a rounding issue that I'm too dumb to find, but here is the code that I'm using:

```
  function PrettyTime( $time )
  {    
    $current = time();

    if ( $time == $current )
      return 'just now';
    if ( $time == 0 )
      return 'a long time ago';

    $time = $current - $time;

    $intervals = array
    (
      'year'   => 29030400,
      'month'  => 2592000,
      'week'   => 604800,
      'day'    => 86400,
      'hour'   => 3600,
      'minute' => 60,
      'second' => 1
    );

    foreach( $intervals as $word => $interval )
    {
      $works = intval( $time / $interval );
      $future = $works < 0;

      if ( !$works )
        continue; /* keep going through, silly! */
      else
      {
        if ( !$future && $works == 1 )
        {
          switch( $word )
          {
            case 'year':  return 'last year';
            case 'month': return 'last month';
            case 'week':  return 'last week';
            case 'day':   return 'yesterday';
            default:      break;
          }
        }
        else
          break;
      }
    }    

    return abs($works) . ' ' . $word . ( $works ? 's' : '') . ($future ? ' in the future' : ' ago');
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually running the code: - it's the `break;` in the `default:` clause. You must use `break 2;` there to break out of the switch **and** the foreach.

Comment: That's great to know. I had no idea php had such a mechanism to do break 2 to break out of two things.

Answer (score 1):

You don't always `break` out of the outer `foreach` loop when you seem to want to.  Try removing the final `else` line and dropping the indent on the `break` statement under it.